# Understanding .vimrc configuration for typescript tooltip symbol

Tags: typescript, vim

I'm using the [Tsuquyomi](https://github.com/Quramy/tsuquyomi) plugin for `typescript` on **vim**. In the documentation of the plugin, they are talking about tool tips for the symbol under the mouse cursor which work as expected.

The problem is that I'm currently using terminal **Vim** and event if I was using **GVim** or any other GUI variation of **Vim** I still wouldn't be using the mouse when working with the editor. I see that they are providing an option for the terminal users which is to add the following line into your `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd FileType typescript nmap <buffer> <Leader>t : <C-u>echo tsuquyomi#hint()<CR>
```

I have already done that but I don't see any changes and since I'm new to Vim I don't know what that line does or how is the tooltip supposed to be used in the terminal.

Do I have to use some key combination in order to trigger the tooltip under the cursor?

Comment: `\t` if `<Leader>` is mapped to `\`, which is default. Have you tried `\t`?

Comment: Yes, @dlmeetei. The `<Leader>` key is mapped to \ by default. This means that `<Leader>t` can executed by default with \+`t`. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to press `<Leader>` (by default this is bound to <kbd>\</kbd> ; cp. `:help leader`) and then `t`. It will only work in Typescript buffers, which can be checked via

```
:setlocal filetype?
```

The syntax for key mappings is `:map {options} {lhs} {rhs}`; i.e. you have to press the keys in `{lhs}` to yield the stuff in `{rhs}`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Very helpful.